# Can the service accounts-daemon be removed/disabled on ubuntu server

Tags: services

`accounts-daemon` service consumes a lot of CPU, I want to know if I can just disable/remove this service altogether! I am on a Ubuntu server instance and not desktop.

i.e. can I purge the package `accountsservice` or `systemctl disable accounts-daemon.service`

Will there be any functionality that will suffer ?

Thanks.

Comment: A stock install of Ubuntu Server does not include any Gnome software nor any graphical desktop software at all, so the question seems curious. Please edit your question to present a real problem that you are actually encountering instead of a hypothetical ("*I have read...*") that you might never encounter.

Comment: GNOME is mentioned in the official wiki: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/AccountsService/
A stock install of Ubuntu 18.04.6 server _does_ install `accountsservice` package

Comment: Hmm. A test install of Ubuntu 22.04 Server does not include the `accountsservice` package nor `accounts-daemon.service`. We no longer answer questions about Ubuntu 18.04 -- it reached End Of Standard Support on 31 May 2023.

Comment: ok, thanks for checking. I see that there is a dependency due to the `ubuntu-standard` (via `language-selector-common`) so, for now, I will go with disabling this service. I just want to know if there will be some feature that get's affected on disabling this service.